# ConTeXt: \setupfloats[indentnext=yes] gives no indentation after a marginfloat if there is a caption

Tags: indentation, context, context-mkiv

I have a problem on indentation after floats. This is a cross post. I asked [on the ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086729.html), but got no response so far.

I'm using marginfloats in a document, and I would like the following paragraph to be indented. It certainly works if I add the keyword `none` when placing the float, but not otherwise. I think the somewhat minimal example below speaks for itself.

(I use an updated standalone ConTeXt  ver: 2016.09.05 10:28 MKIV beta  fmt: 2016.9.5  int: english/english)

```
\usemodule[ipsum]

\setupindenting[yes,medium]

\setupfloats[indentnext=yes]

\starttext

\ipsum[alternative=lines,n=4]

\placefigure[outermargin,high]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, but it is not! On the other hand, it has
a caption, as I want. \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=6]

\placefigure[outermargin,high,none]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, and it is! But I want the caption, and
hence note use the \type{none} keyword.
\ipsum[alternative=lines,n=3]
\stoptext
```

[image: image of result]

PS1: There is also [an old thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/058133.html) on the ConTeXt mailing list with a similar problem, but I don't see how that solves my problem.

PS2: I could add `\indentation` after all `\placefigure`s, but I would not like to do this manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ConTeXt does not honor `indentnext` after some float parameters. I believe that it is honored only after `top` and `here`. I never understood the design rationale behind it.

Having said that, a modified version of the code linked in the [thread that you linked to](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/058152.html) does work:

```
\usemodule[ipsum]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\unprotect
\def\page_one_place_float_auto   {\page_one_place_float_otherwise\useindentnextparameter\floatparameter}
\def\page_one_place_float_bottom {\page_one_place_float_otherwise\useindentnextparameter\floatparameter}
\def\page_one_place_float_margin {\page_margin_blocks_process_float\useindentnextparameter\floatparameter}
\def\page_one_place_float_leftmargin {\page_one_place_float_side_indeed\page_sides_process_float_leftmargin\useindentnextparameter\floatparameter}
\def\page_one_place_float_rightmargin{\page_one_place_float_side_indeed\page_sides_process_float_rightmargin\useindentnextparameter\floatparameter}
\protect


\setupindenting[yes,medium]

\setupfloats[indentnext=yes]

\starttext

\ipsum[alternative=lines,n=4]

\placefigure[outermargin,high]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, but it is not! On the other hand, it has
a caption, as I want. \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=6]

\placefigure[bottom]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, but it is not! On the other hand, it has
a caption, as I want. \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=6]

\placefigure[outermargin,high,none]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, and it is! But I want the caption, and
hence note use the \type{none} keyword.
\ipsum[alternative=lines,n=3]

\page

\ipsum[alternative=lines,n=4]

\placefigure[outermargin,high]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, but it is not! On the other hand, it has
a caption, as I want. \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=6]

\placefigure[bottom]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, but it is not! On the other hand, it has
a caption, as I want. \ipsum[alternative=lines,n=6]

\placefigure[outermargin,high,none]{}{\blackrule[width=1cm,height=1cm]}

This paragraph should be indented, and it is! But I want the caption, and
hence note use the \type{none} keyword.
\ipsum[alternative=lines,n=3]

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Aditya! This solves the problem, also in my larger document (which actually had a slightly more complex setup). I'm a bit curious on the "design rationale" behind this, but perhaps we will never know...

Comment: Is `indentafter` a synonym for `indentnext`?

Comment: @HenriMenke: Good catch! Basically `indentafter` was being ignored; context was simply **always** indenting. I needed to use `\useindentnextparamenter\floatparameter` instead of `\nonoindentation` in the definitions.

Comment: @Aditya Will your fix go into core at some point?  I've seen the post on the mailing list but Hans did not respond yet and Wolfgang suggested this MKII compatible thingee.  Do you know who has push-access to the ConTeXt development code?

Comment: I'm sorry for the `indentnext`/`indentafter` mess. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I don't know if it will end up in the core. The final decision is Hans'.