# ConTeXt: break paragraph after t-vim code block

Tags: context, block, t-vim

### I will edit this question here:

I would like the `\startc` to work like `$$math$$`.

```
\starttext
In C, the program to print hello, world is
\startc
My C code here.
\stopc

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.

In C, the program to print hello, world is
$$
My C code here.
$$

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.
\stoptext
```

[image]

I would like the `\inlinec` to work like `$math$`.

```
\starttext
This means that every program must have a \inlinec{main} somewhere.

\inlinec{main} will usually call other

This means that every program must have a \inlinec{main} somewhere.

$main$ will usually call other
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

Question before edit:

Would like to have a new paragraph right after the t-vim code block.
I made it work by adding `{\ \vskip -1\baselineskip}` after the code block.
But it is dirty.

What is the right way to do this in ConTeXt?

```
\parindent=20mm
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping[c][margin=20mm]
\definevimtyping[sh][margin=20mm]
\starttext
In C, the program to print \quotation{\inlinesh{hello, world}} is
\startc
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
\stopc%{\ \vskip -1\baselineskip}%the paragraph should break here, but..

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.
\stoptext
```

Without paragraph break:
[image]

With paragraph break:
[image]

Comment: Do you use `\parindent` to set the paragraph indent. It is better to use the ConTeXt interface for setting indent: `\setupindenting[20mm,yes]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to achieve the behaviour that you want is `indentnext=auto`. However, there was a bug in `t-filter` module due to which `indentnext=auto` did not work correctly. I uploaded a new version of `t-filter` (ver: 2018.08.10) with the bugfix.

For the inline code, what you are seeing is because `\inlinec` occurs at the beginning of the line (you would see the same behaviour if `{\bold Hello}` occurs at the beginning of the line). This can be fixed by using `\dontleavehmode` (or adding `left=\dontleavehmode`) as an option to `definevimtyping`. I uploaded a new version of `t-vim` (ver: 2018.08.10) with the bugfix.

For the sake of completeness, I have left my old answer below.

**OLD ANSWER**
The right answer is `indentnext=auto`, but that does not work due to a regression bug. Here is a quick fix that works on the minimal example. I will test it a bit more, and then release a new version of `t-filter` with the fix:

```
\usemodule[vim]

% THIS IS THE BUGFIX:
\unprotect
\starttexdefinition externalfilter@process_filter
     % By defualt, buffers are in memory in MkIV. So, we save them to disk
     %
     %      \savebuffer[\externalfilter@buffer_name][\externalfilter@input_file]
     %
     % We can also save a list of buffers to a file. The empty
     % elements of the list are ignored. So, instead we use the following
     %
     %    \savebuffer[\externalfilterparameter{\c!buffer\c!before},
     %                \externalfilter@buffer_name,
     %                \externalfilterparameter{\c!buffer\c!after}]
     %               [\externalfilter@input_file]}
     %
     % but using this method we cannot save the file in another directory. 
     % So, we use the key-value interface for \savebuffer.
         \externalfilter@check_writable \externalfilter@input_file
         \savebuffer
           [
              \c!list={\externalfilterparameter{\c!buffer\c!before},
                       \externalfilter@buffer_name,
                       \externalfilterparameter{\c!buffer\c!after}},
              \c!file={\externalfilter@input_file},
              \c!prefix=\v!no,
            ]
     \externalfilter@execute_filter
     \externalfilter@read_processed_file
     \iftraceexternalfilters \else 
        \doif{\externalfilterparameter\c!purge}\v!yes
             {\ctxlua{os.remove(\!!bs\externalfilter@input_file\!!es)}}
     \fi
    \endgroup % Moved before \dorechecknextindentation

     % Finalization
     \doifinset{\externalfilterparameter\c!cache}{\v!yes,\v!force}
         {\doglobal\incrementvalue\externalfilter@count}

    \doif{\externalfilterparameter\c!location}\v!paragraph
        {\useindentnextparameter\externalfilterparameter
          \dorechecknextindentation}
\stoptexdefinition

% Invisible space
\installspacemethod {\????syntaxhighlighting\v!off}
  {\unexpanded\def\obeyedspace
      {\mathortext\normalspace
          {\syntaxhighlighting@split\interwordspace\relax}}%
   \letcharcode\spaceasciicode\obeyedspace}
```

\protect
    \protect

```
\definevimtyping[c][syntax=c,margin=20mm, indentnext=auto]
\setupindenting[20mm,yes]
\setupformula[indentnext=auto]

\starttext
In C, the program to print hello, world is
\startc
My C code here.
\stopc

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.

In C, the program to print hello, world is
\startformula
My C code here.
\stopformula

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.


This means that every program must have a \inlinec{main} somewhere.

\dontleavehmode\inlinec{main} will usually call other

This means that every program must have a \inlinec{main} somewhere.

$main$ will usually call other
\stoptext
```

The above example also shows how to fix the issue with inline code. Basically, when you start a new paragraph with `\inlinec` you need to preface that with `\dontleavehmode`. You can automate that by adding `left=\dontleavehmode` in `\definevimtyping`.

There wass another bug: an extra white space before `\inlinec`, which the above code also fixes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The suppression of indentation by environments can be resolved using the `indentnext=yes` option. The following seems to give what you want:

```
\setupindenting[20mm,yes]

\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[c][margin=20mm,indentnext=yes]
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[c][margin=20mm]
\definevimtyping[sh][margin=20mm]
\starttext

In C, the program to print \quotation{\inlinesh{hello, world}} is

\startc
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
\stopc

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.
\stoptext
```

For reference, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328147/context-setupfloatsindentnext-yes-gives-no-indentation-after-a-marginfloat-i) seems to be related as it pertains to indent suppression.

**Update:**

The mention of `$$...$$` equation block in the comments makes me think the question isn't just about indentation, but also about spacing above and below the block. This spacing can be modified using `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` options:

```
\setupindenting[20mm,yes]

\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[c]
  [margin=20mm,
   indentnext=yes,
   spacebefore=line,
   spaceafter=line]
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[c][margin=20mm]
\definevimtyping[sh][margin=20mm]
\starttext

In C, the program to print \quotation{\inlinesh{hello, world}} is

\startc
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
\stopc

Just how to run this program depends on the system you are using.
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem can be fixed by saying `\startc[indentnext=yes]` (This will not break the paragraph, only add the indentation to the next line). Similar problem occurs, when `\inlinec` appears at the beginning/end of a paragraph.

Comment: This is by design and this how indentation works with all environments in ConTeXt. See [the wiki page for details](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Indentation). @LittlePony: I don't understand your comment "This will not break the paragraph, only add indentation", what do you mean by "break the paragraph". Do you want whitespace after the code environment and the start of next line. If so, you can use `spaceafter=line` or `spaceafter=small`, etc.

Comment: @Aditya. I'm new to ConTeXt. I mean... I would like the inline code to work as `$math$` and the block to work as `$$math$$`, like in plain TeX.

Comment: @LittlePony It would help to know what features of `$$math$$` you are specifically interested in. I took a guess in the update to my answer, but I'm still not sure what you mean. For example, is the 20mm indent actually meant to be a margin?

Comment: @ssokolen You are so kind! A blank line in code will break paragraphs in Plain TeX. If you put `$$math$$` at the end (without a blank line) of a paragraph, put a blank line under the math block, put some text under the blank line, then you will find the paragraph breaks after the math block. How ever, if you remove the blank line between the math block and the text under the block, then you will find that the math block and the text under it belong to the same paragraph. You can replace all the `\startc` and `\stopc` with `$$` and replace all the `\inlinec{#1}` with `$#1$` to see what happens.

Comment: @LittePony: Use `intentnext=auto` for indenting to work like plain tex and latex.

Comment: @Aditya. Nope, not about `indentnext=auto`. I edited the question, and it is clearer.

Comment: @LittlePony: Given the changes to your question, I would recommend you accept Aditya's answer if it resolves your problem.